# Self maps on Stiefel Manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, stiefel-manifolds

Let $m_l: S^{n-1} \stackrel{z \mapsto z^l}{\to} S^{n-1}$ be a  map of spheres.  Then it induces a map on $( S^{n-1})^k$, given by product. Note the Stiefel manifold $V_k(\mathbb{R^{n}})$, the collection of orthonormal $k$-frames in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed subset of $( S^{n-1})^k.$

My question is: What is the induce map of $m_l$ on $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, $z\mapsto z^l$ is bad notation for what I presume you mean to be the degree $l$ self-map $S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^{n-1}$, since for $n\neq 1,2,4,8$ the sphere $S^{n-1}$ is not an H-space and has no product. Secondly, what makes you think the image $m_l(V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset (S^{n-1})^k$ is contained in $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$?